# Redirection to index() function when function not found in Codeigniter _remap() function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an error when I do something like this :

```
public function _remap()
    {
        $firstURISegment = $this->uri->segment(1);
        $secondURISegment = $this->uri->segment(2);
        if($firstURISegment == "user")
        {
            if($secondURISegment == "")
            {
                echo "USER INDEX";
            }
            else
            {
                $this->$secondURISegment();
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            echo $firstURISegment;               
        }
    }
```

And I get this error when I call a function that is not defined in class by this `www.example.com/user/abcd`.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method user::abcd() in C:\xampp\htdocs\livears\application\controllers\user.php on line 17
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined method user::abcd()

Filename: controllers/user.php

Line Number: 17

Backtrace:
```

Instead of this error I want to redirect to the `index()` function of this class. How can I ? 
And please see, I have done this:

```
$route[':any'] = 'user/$1';
```

in `routes.php` for getting `www.example.com/username` instead of `www.example.com/user/username`. And as my User class has other functions I have remaped to call those but as you see if I call an undefined function I get a `Fatal error`. Please help me with redirection.

Comment: Just a note: CI 3 versions you must have the **first letter only** of class and filenames upper case User.php

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Ohkk.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the name of controller should start with capital letter

Your _remap is not doing anything to redirect. Use it like this

```
public function _remap()
    {
        $firstURISegment = $this->uri->segment(1);
        $secondURISegment = $this->uri->segment(2);
        if($firstURISegment == "user")
        {
            if($secondURISegment == "")
            {
                echo "USER INDEX";
            }
            else
            {
                If ( function_exists ($secondURISegment))
             {  $this->$secondURISegment();}
              else {
                  redirect('index');
                   }
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            echo $firstURISegment;               
        }
    }
```

Do you get the idea ? Now implement it in your code ?

Comment: It will not work if you type exactly what is written here. You have to customize it according to your code. I have just gave the idea how it should happen